# If $ A \in B $ and $ B \subseteq C $ then $ A \in C $. vs. If $ A \in B $ and $ B \subseteq C $ then $ A \subseteq C $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-proofs

I am trying to decipher the difference between the following two statements:

> If $ A \in B $ and $ B \subseteq C $ then $ A \in C $.

vs.

> If $ A \in B $ and $ B \subseteq C $ then $ A \subseteq C $.

I think the first statement is the true statement and the 2nd is false because of $ A \in B $ not $A \subseteq B $

Am I on the right track? How would I give a simple counter example to show the statement is false?

Comment: You are on the right track. The first is, in some places, the definition of $B\subseteq C$.

Comment: see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064663/x-in-x-or-not/1064730#1064730)

Comment: @Alyssa Wallace: please mark "accept" for one answer (that you think is the best) and exclude the question from "unaccepted  list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right. That is pretty much the definition of a subset.

For the second statement consider

$A:=\{1\}$, $B:=\{\{1\},2\}$ and $C:=\{\{1\},2,3\}$.

Then $A\in B$, $B\subseteq C$, but $A\not\subseteq C$, since $1\notin C$.

Comment: Does the notation of the brackets make a difference? Can you just have $ B $ be the set $ \{1, 2\} $ and $ C $ be the set $ \{1,2,3\} $

Comment: @Alyssa Wallace Sure but then $ A $ isn't a set so $ A\subseteq C $ makes no sense.

Comment: @Uncountable as commented above $A=1$ is still a set under usual mathematical assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Another example.  These are true
$$
-5 \in \mathbb Z\quad\text{and}\quad \mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Q
$$
and it follows that
$$
-5 \in \mathbb Q
$$
but it does not follow that
$$
-5 \subseteq \mathbb Q
$$

Answer (score 0):

First statement:

if A is an element in B, and B is a subset of C, then A is in C.

Explanation: this is true because B being a subset of C means that every element in B is also in C.

Second statement:

if A is an element in B and B is a subset of C, then A is a subset of C.

Explanation: this is false because the element A is not necessarily a set. For example, let $C = \{1,2,3\}$. Let $B = \{1,2\}$. Let $A$ be $1$. $1$ is not a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$ -- it is a member.

Hypothetically: $\{1\}$, on the other hand, would be a subset.

Comment: If you subscribe to modern foundation theory just about everything is a set. The example you give is correct but under usual assumptions if $A=1$, $B=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{0,1,2\}$ then $A\in B$ $B\subseteq C$ and $A\subseteq C$ since if you parse what $A$ is given the Von Neuman definition of ordinals you end up having $A=\{\{\}\}$ and $0=\{\}$.