# Conceptual Doubt with Sets regarding empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So the empty set $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set.

So $\emptyset \subset \{1,2,3\}$

But why isn't

$\{\emptyset\} \subset \{1,2,3,\{6,7\}\}$

Shouldn't it be valid because {..other objects..{6,7}} contain every object present in {${\emptyset}} which is nothing.

and even if we enclose a empty set inside a set isn't it still going to create another empty set?

$\{\emptyset\} = \{\{\}\}$ is this equal to $\{\}$ since there is nothing inside.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: $\{\emptyset\} \subset \{1,2,3,\{6,7\}\}$ would be true iff $\emptyset$ is a member of $\{1,2,3,\{6,7\}\}$.

Comment: @Clarinetist. No. $\{1\}$ and $\{\{1\}\}$ are two different sets.

Comment: Suppose $x=\{\;\{\}\;\}$ . This means $\forall y\;(y\in x\iff y=\{\}\;)$. So if $y$ is the empty set then $ y\in x.$  So $x$ has a member ( namely, $\phi \in x$) .So $x$ is not  the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

1) $\{ \emptyset \} \not\subset \{1,2,3,\{6,7\}\}$, because $\emptyset \not \in \{1,2,3,\{6,7\}\}$.

Indeed, $\emptyset \neq 1$ , $\emptyset \neq 2$,  $\emptyset \neq 3$ and  $\emptyset \neq \{6,7\}$

2) $\{\}$ could be a notation for $\emptyset$, it's unusual (= not used) and prone to missunderstanding, but it's logical.

Comment: But doesn't {6,7} contain $\emptyset$. If A is a subset of B then B contains everything present in A, so doesn't this mean everything in A belongs to B?

Comment: @UianMail : $\emptyset \neq \{ 6,7 \}$, and it's all that matter. You don't say that $3 \subset \{1,2, \{3,4\} \}$ either

Comment: @UianMail You may be confused about how these symbols are pronounced. $\emptyset$ is *contained* in $\{ 6,7 \}$; symbolically $\emptyset \subseteq \{ 6,7 \}$. But it is not an *element* of $\{ 6,7 \}$; symbolically $\emptyset \not \in \{ 6,7 \}$. The empty set can be an element of a set because it is an object in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

$\emptyset$ *is a subset* of every set; *not a member* of every set.
$\{\emptyset\}$ is not empty; it has a member; namely $\emptyset$.
By definition, $A\subseteq B$ iff every element of $A$ is contained in $B$.
Is $\emptyset$ an element of $\{1,2,3,\{6,7\}\}$?  in other words:
Is $\emptyset$ one of these elements : $1,2,3,$ or $\{6,7\}$?

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064663/x-in-x-or-not/1064730#1064730) you can see good question and answer about using "{}" in set theory.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) “and even if we enclose a empty set inside a set isn't it still going to create another empty set?”**
: Roughly, $∅$ means *‘a box which contains nothing’*.  {$∅$} means a box which contains *another box which contains nothing*. They are not the same. So, {$∅$} is not empty, it contains an object.
**(2) "{∅}={{}} is this equal to {} since there is nothing inside."**
: No, they are not equal. {$∅$} means a box B which contains an empty box A. {} means the box A which contains nothing.